# VectorAssembler output only to DenseVector?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

There is something very annoying with the function of VectorAssembler.
I am currently transforming a set of columns into a single column of
vectors and then use the StandardScaler function to apply the scaling
to the included features. However, there seems that SPARK for memory
reasons, decides whether it should use a DenseVector or a SparseVector to represent each row of features.
But, when you need to use StandardScaler, the input of SparseVector(s)
is invalid, only DenseVectors are allowed. Does anybody know a solution to that?

**Edit:**
I decided to just use a UDF function instead, which turns the 
sparse vector into a dense vector. Kind of silly but works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right that `VectorAssembler` chooses dense vs sparse output format based on whichever one uses less memory.

You don't need a UDF to convert from `SparseVector` to `DenseVector`; just use [`toArray()` method](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector.toArray):

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector, DenseVector 
a = SparseVector(4, [1, 3], [3.0, 4.0])
b = DenseVector(a.toArray())
```

Also, `StandardScaler` accepts `SparseVector` unless you set `withMean=True` at creation. If you do need to de-mean, you have to deduct a (presumably non-zero) number from all the components, so the sparse vector won't be sparse any more.

Comment: If I don't know the type, I can't call toArray in a map function

Comment: More detail please. Full source code how to make VectorAssembler output dense vector.

Answer (score -4):

you can convert it to dense vector after the VectorAssembler transforms it to sparse vector.

Here is what i did,

Create a DenseVector case class

```
case class vct(features:Vector)
```

transform the sparse vector column to dense vector column

`val new_df = df.select("sparse vector column").map(x => {
       vct(x.getAs[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector](1).toDense)}).toDF()`

Comment: Question is in PySpark not Scala.