# SparseVector vs DenseVector when using StandardScaler

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

I'm using the following code to normalize a PySpark DataFrame

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import StandardScaler, VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

cols = ["a", "b", "c"]
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 0, 3), (2, 3, 2), (1, 3, 1), (3, 0, 3)], cols)

Pipeline(stages=[
    VectorAssembler(inputCols=cols, outputCol='features'), 
    StandardScaler(withMean=True, inputCol='features', outputCol='scaledFeatures')
]).fit(df).transform(df).select(cols + ['scaledFeatures']).head()
```

This gives the expected result:

```
Row(a=1, b=0, c=3, scaledFeatures=DenseVector([-0.7833, -0.866, 0.7833]))
```

However when I run the Pipeline on a (much) larger dataset, loaded from a parquet file I receive the following exception:

```
16/12/21 09:47:50 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 60.0 (TID 6370, 10.231.153.67): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfu
n$2: (vector) => vector)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply2_2$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:112)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:504)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1877)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:269)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Do not support vector type class org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.StandardScalerModel.transform(StandardScaler.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScalerModel$$anonfun$2.apply(StandardScaler.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScalerModel$$anonfun$2.apply(StandardScaler.scala:167)
        ... 13 more
```

I notice that here the VectorAssembler has converted my columns into a mllib.linalg.SparseVector rather than the DenseVector used in the first case.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: spark 2.0.1. Pretty sure this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844330/vectorassembler-output-only-to-densevector holds the key. Trying to convert the SparseVector to a DenseVector at the moment, but that's not straight-forward either.

Comment: isn't "b = DenseVector(a.toArray())" a straight-forward solution?

Comment: Still a bit of a newbie with Spark. I was figuring out how to apply that transform to a column in a dataframe. Is a udf the best way to go? Eg. asDense = udf(lambda s: DenseVector(s.toArray()), VectorUDT())
df = df.withColumn('features', asDense(df.features))

Comment: Also would be nice to add that as a transform in the Pipeline, but I'm not sure how to add arbitrary transforms yet....

Comment: I guess that I'd use UDF in order to apply a transform to a column. (assuming that simple column.cast() won't help here).

Comment: Sometimes this is due to `null`s in the original data... Make sure your UDFs handle the case when the input is null

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I noticed that you wanted to create this into a custom transform to include it directly in your pipeline.

This should do that for you.

```
from pyspark import keyword_only  
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import Transformer  
from pyspark.ml.param.shared import HasInputCol, HasOutputCol
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector, DenseVector, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


class AsDenseTransformer(Transformer, HasInputCol, HasOutputCol):  
    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None):
        super(AsDenseTransformer, self).__init__()
        kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
        self.setParams(**kwargs)

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None):
        kwargs = self.setParams._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)

    def _transform(self, dataset):
        out_col = self.getOutputCol()
        in_col = dataset[self.getInputCol()]

        asDense = udf(lambda s: DenseVector(s.toArray()), VectorUDT()) 

        return dataset.withColumn(out_col,  asDense(in_col))
```

Once you have defined it, you can initialize it as a transform to be included in your pipeline after the vectorassembler.

```
Pipeline(stages=[
    VectorAssembler(inputCols=cols, outputCol='features'),
    AsDenseTransformer(inputCol='features', outputCol='features'),
    StandardScaler(withMean=True, inputCol='features', outputCol='scaledFeatures')
]).fit(df).transform(df).select(cols + ['scaledFeatures']).head()
```