# Make VectorAssembler always choose DenseVector

Tags: python, pyspark

This is the structure of my dataframe using `df.columns`.

```
['LastName',
 'FirstName',
 'Stud. ID',
 '10 Relations',
 'Related to Politics',
 '3NF',
 'Documentation & Scripts',
 'SQL',
 'Data (CSV, etc.)',
 '20 Relations',
 'Google News',
 'Cheated',
 'Sum',
 'Delay Factor',
 'Grade (out of 2)']
```

I have transformed this dataframe in pyspark using

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['10 Relations',
 'Related to Politics',
 '3NF'],outputCol='features')
```

and `output = assembler.transform(df)`. Now it contains some Row objects. These objects have this architecture (This is what I get when I run `output.printSchema()`)

```
root
 |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Stud. ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 10 Relations: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Related to Politics: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 3NF: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Documentation & Scripts: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- SQL: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Data (CSV, etc.): integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 20 Relations: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Google News: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Cheated: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Sum: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Delay Factor: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Grade (out of 2): double (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

For each row, the assembler chooses to make the features vector Sparse or Dense (For memory reasons). But this is a big problem. Because I want to use this transformed data for making a linear regression model. So, I'm searching for a way to make VectorAssembler always choose Dense Vector.

Any idea?

Note: I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844330/vectorassembler-output-only-to-densevector). But the problem is that since the Row class is a subclass of tuple, I cannot change a Row object after it is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sparse and Dense vector are both inherited from pyspark.ml.linalg.Vector. So both vector types have `.toarray()` method in common. You can convert them into numpy array then Dense vetor with simple udf.

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector, SparseVector, Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *


v = Vectors.dense([1,3]) # dense vector
u = SparseVector(2, {}) # sparse vector

# toDense function converts both vector  type into Dense Vector
toDense = lambda v: Vectors.dense(v.toArray()) 
toDense(u), toDense(v)
```

Results:

```
DenseVector([0.0, 0.0]), DenseVector([1.0, 3.0])
```

Then You can create udf with this function.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ((v,)), 
    ((u,))
   ], ['feature'])

toDense = lambda v: Vectors.dense(v.toArray())
toDenseUdf = F.udf(toDense, VectorUDT())
df.withColumn('feature', toDenseUdf('feature')).show()
```

results:

```
+---------+
|  feature|
+---------+
|[1.0,3.0]|
|[0.0,0.0]|
+---------+
```

You have single vectortype in column.

Comment: You can use this funtion ---> _convert_vector